# asp.net MVC routing - javascript url 404 errors

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, http-status-code-404, iis-7.5, url-routing

While developing my app (asp.net mvc3) locally everything was fine using the VS dev app server. The app was located at localhost/. However, I'm attempting to deploy the application on a IIS 7.5 server in a /Management directory and having a lot of routing issues as a few calls in my app rely on the app being at the route.

I have some javascript code that calls my controller through an ajax call that looks like this:

```
url: "/en/Home/GetFormula/"
```

I would like it to go to: /Management/en/Home/GetFormula but instead it's going to the root of the site and looking for /en/Home/GetFormula and returning 404 errors.

Any ideas on how I can fix my javascript routing to default /Management/ as the root of the site?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the pseudo-URL passed to an HTTP request begins with a slash (e.g. "/path/to/resource"), the pseudo-URL is "completed" by treating it as if the given path were under the Web site's root directory (e.g. "http://my.site/path/to/directory").

Clearly, you were expecting the pseudo-URL to be processed as if the given path were under your Web application's root directory. Well, I have bad news for you: The HTTP protocol does not deal with such a thing as a "Web application".

The ASP.NET MVC Framework provides the `Url.Content` function, which takes pseudo-URLs beginning with a tilde character (e.g., "~/path/to/resource") and returns the result of replacing the tilde character with the Web application's root directory (e.g., "http://my.site/an/application/path/to/resource", assuming the Web application's root directory is "http:/my.site/an/application"). However, the ASP.NET MVC Framework is only available on the server side. If your JavaScript runs on the client side, it cannot call `Url.Content`.

But not all is lost. The ASP.NET MVC Framework [allows you to dynamically generate JavaScript code on the server and run it on the client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.javascript.aspx), the same way it [allows you to dynamically generate HTML content and of course send it to the client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view.aspx). That way, you can expand the pseudo-URLs into actual URLs *on the server side*, and deploy the resulting JavaScript code to the client.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusion about where you are currently try:

```
url: document.URL + "/Management/Home/GetFormula"
```

Comment: This does not work if the current document's URL is buried deep inside the (possibly virtual) directory structure.

Comment: Are you trying to get the location of the js file itself?

Comment: I am not trying to do anything. I am not the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue adding a html hidden field on my page where, on the server side, I put the correct url inferred with the Url.RouteUrl method like this:

```
<input id="MyHiddenFieldName" name="MyHiddenFieldName" type="hidden" value="@Url.RouteUrl(new { area = "MyArea", controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction" />
```

then, on your javascript code you could do this:

```
url: $("#MyHiddenFieldName).val()
```